# Backbone doesn't load my Jquery UI slider after sliding

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js

I have an event slidechange which set and save the new value, I also have a bind on change which reload the render with the new data, but the problem is that the render don't load my JQuery UI Slider after changing. Here are the part of code concerned

```
//my bind on change
this.collection.bind('change',this.render);
//my event when slide, editPriority set and save the new value
"slidechange #priority": "editPriority"
$('#priority').slider();
```

For information the JQuery UI Slider is loaded once the page is loaded

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit too less code shown here. Where is `$('#priority').slider();` called ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `$('#priority').slider();` is called in your `render` method.

Comment: But then we're reinitializing the plugin on each render, no?

Comment: @Hugo, yes, that's exactly the idea.  You have to reinitialize to attach the slider to the new DOM element.  When you re-render, the old DOM element for the slider is throw away.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply update the value in the render method by doing .slider( "value", 55 ) and move the slicer initialisation to the View.init method.

I also have a View.clear method that is called when the view is removed and this calls .slider( "destroy" ) to remove listeners & clean up.